# Multiple simultaneous sessions of R studio in Linux Environment

Tags: rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, centos7, rstudio-server, rserve

I am running RStudio Server and it runs great. However, if two Sessions We try to log in at the same time it disconnects the previous Session and says " 
R Session Disconnected
This browser was disconnected from the R session because another browser connected (only one browser at a time may be connected to an RStudio session). You may reconnect using the button below."

Is there any way for two (or more) Sessions with the same user to be running this at the same time? Thanks

Note: I am facing this problem in the Linux Environments only

Comment: Multiple sessions for the same users are available only with RStudio Server Pro.

Comment: Thanks..!!. Are there any options through command line we can run the scripts simultaneously?